# Importing GoPro MP4 videos into Python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, mp4

I am working on an OpenCV project with GoPro cameras in Python (2.7).  I am looking for a way to bring these video files into OpenCV for analysis.  Here are the issues that I am having, any recommendations would be greatly appreciated:

1. I can only get OpenCV (2.3) to recognize raw AVI files.  Converting MP4 to raw AVI resulted in huge files and was capped at 2gb (~30 secs.).
2. pyFFmpeg only works on Python 2.6.
3. pyMedia doesn't work on mp4's, which the GoPro exports.

Ideally, I would read in the mp4 file, and create a loop to decode the frame, save it, analyze, encode and export.  I am running out of ideas.  Any thoughts?

Comment: OpenCV2 can now deal with MP4's if you have the correct codec and they are set-up correctly.